# mvc sending mails from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, windows-services

I have a MVC application, it also needs to send email to client.
When sending emails the mail servers might be down. So i thought of storing them in database.
What are the options that I could implement in my application that could take care checking database table and sending emails that are not sent?

Has someone done this before? Any tips.

Answer (score 1):

Should be pretty straightforward.  You'd essentially have two applications sharing the same database:

- MVC Application
- Windows Service Application

The MVC application would write mail messages to the database.  You can store the information in any structure you like, as long as it has enough information to construct an email message.  Additionally each record would have a "sent" flag (or "sent on" date, or some other way to record if/when it was sent).

The Windows Service would periodically (every hour? every minute? etc.) check the database for "unsent" messages.  One by one it can attempt to send them.  Any time it succeeds (well, as far as it knows anyway, as long as there's no error from the mail server) it updates that record indicating if/when it was sent.

Do this for each record each time.  As individual messages are successfully sent, they're updated and won't be attempted again.  If there's an error, it's skipped and the process continues with the other messages.  For any given error I also recommend recording that error as part of the data so that you can later inspect issues.  For example, if one message consistently fails, then the problem could be with the message itself and not the mail server.  Recording the errors somewhere would allow you to fix that.

Comment: it may sound stupid but I haven't worked with windows service before. How does the connection to database work from this windows service application. Database I generate is using code first. Currently in my MVC application I use entity framework to get or do anything with database. Any tips?

Comment: @Biplov13: A Windows Service is a .NET application just like anything else.  The same code would work.  Ideally in this scenario you would put all of your data access code in a Class Library and both the MVC application and the Window Service application would reference that Class Library, sharing the same data access code.